# CLLocationManager EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, cllocationmanager, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm using `GoogleMaps` for my app and I properly setup everything from the `Info.plist`, `locationManager...didChangeAuthorization` using `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` how every I still get stuck with error

> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

even though I set it properly.  Here is my code below.

```
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate)!, zoom: zoomLevel)
self.mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
self.view = self.mapView
self.initializeTheLocationManager()
self.mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
```

here is my locationManager delegate

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .authorizedAlways || status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
        mapView.delegate = self
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    } else {
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
}
```

**Note**: It seems that I requested twice for `requestWhenInUseAuthorization`.

Comment: Where exactly does it crash?

Comment: what is problem you can face?

Comment: @mag_zbc this `self.locationManager.location?.coordinate)!` it returns `nil` for some reason even though I already allow the simulator for request location.

Comment: In Simulater, you cannot get current location. you should use real device for this

Comment: @AlvinQuezon have you added custom location to your simulator?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni already did

Comment: @TaimoorSuleman but I already set custom location on simulator perhaps it should work right?

Comment: It should work. Can you share demo project?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni, sorry but I can't, this is a commercial product, perhaps it has something to do with the simulator itself.

Comment: May be you can make a separate project and check if you are getting same error with it. and if you think its simulator issue then reset it and set custom location again and check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot work.

`startUpdatingLocation` works **asynchronously**. You have to implement `didUpdateLocations`.

```
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

...

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: (locations[0].coordinate, zoom: zoomLevel)
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    self.mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
    self.view = self.mapView
    self.initializeTheLocationManager()
    self.mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
}
```